# OpenCV FAST Algorithm creating skewed keypoints on only part of an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV's [FAST](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d5/d51/group__features2d__main.html#ga816d870cbdca71c6790c71bdf17df099) corner detection algorithm to get an outline of an image of a ball (Not my final project, I'm using it as a simple example). For some reason, it only works on a third of the input Mat, and stretches the Keypoints across the image. I'm not sure as to what could be going wrong here to make the FAST algorithm not apply to the entire Mat.

Code:

```
void featureDetection(const Mat& imgIn, std::vector<KeyPoint>& pointsOut)   { 
    int fast_threshold = 20;
    bool nonmaxSuppression = true;
    FAST(imgIn, pointsOut, fast_threshold, nonmaxSuppression);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Mat out = imread("ball.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);

    // Detect features 
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    featureDetection(out.clone(), keypoints);
    Mat out2 = out.clone();

    // Draw features (Normal, missing right side)
    for(KeyPoint p : keypoints) {
        drawMarker(out, Point(p.pt.x / 3, p.pt.y), Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    }

    imwrite("out.jpg", out, std::vector<int>(0));
    
    // Draw features (Stretched)
    for(KeyPoint p : keypoints) {
        drawMarker(out2, Point(p.pt.x, p.pt.y), Scalar(127, 0, 255));
    }

    imwrite("out2.jpg", out2, std::vector<int>(0));
}
```

Input image

[image: ball.jpg]

Output 1 (*keypoint.x multiplied by a factor of 1/3, but missing right side*)

[image: out.jpg]

Output 2 (*Coordinates untouched*)

[image: out2.jpg]

I'm using OpenCV 4.5.4 on MinGW.

Comment: Can you try to give a single channel (cvtColor cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY to the keypoint detection?

Comment: @Micka That did it! I'm not sure why, could you post an explanation?

Comment: the "missing right side" could be due to the choice of "threshold"

Comment: I think the right side is missing because every bgr pixel that has higher x than 1/3 of image width will fall out of the grayscale interpreted version of that memory

Comment: If FAST uses without channel-count-checking something like for(x=0; x<img.width; ++x) img.at<uchar>(y,x) then it will only see 1/3 of the original width when img is 3-channel, becauss every pixel is processed 3 times. Once in each channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most keypoint detectors use grayscale images as input.
If you interpret the memory of a bgr image as grayscale, you will have 3 times the number of pixels. Y axis is still ok if the algorithm uses the width-offset per row, which most algorithms do (because this is useful when subimaging or padding is used).

I don't know whether it is a bug or a feature, that FAST doesn't check for the number of channels snd doesnt throw an exception if the wrong number of channels ist given.

You can convert the image to grayscale by cv::cvtColor with the flag cv:: COLOR_BGR2GRAY